# python lxml xpath AttributeError (NoneType) with correct xpath and usually working

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, attributeerror, nonetype

I am trying to migrate a forum to phpbb3 with python/xpath. Although I am pretty new to python and xpath, it is going well. However, I need help with an error.

(The [source file](http://www.razyboard.com/system/morethread-alte-korken-fruchtweinkeller-89069-6046822-0.html) has been downloaded and processed with tagsoup.)

Firefox/Firebug show xpath: `/html/body/table[5]/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td/a[3]/b`

(in my script without tbody)

Here is an abbreviated version of my code:

```
forumfile="morethread-alte-korken-fruchtweinkeller-89069-6046822-0.html"
XPOSTS = "/html/body/table[5]/tr[position()>1]"
t = etree.parse(forumfile)
allposts = t.xpath(XPOSTS)

XUSER = "td[1]/a[3]/b"
XREG = "td/span"
XTIME = "td[2]/table/tr/td[1]/span"
XTEXT = "td[2]/p"
XSIG = "td[2]/i"
XAVAT = "td/img[last()]"

XPOSTITEL = "/html/body/table[3]/tr/td/table/tr/td/div/h3"
XSUBF = "/html/body/table[3]/tr/td/table/tr/td/div/strong[position()=1]"

for p in allposts:
    unreg=0
    username = None
    username = p.find(XUSER).text          #this is where it goes haywire
```

When the loop hits user "tompson" / position()=11 at the end of the file, I get

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I've tried a lot of `try except else finallys`, but they weren't helpful.

I am getting much more information later in the script such as date of post, date of user registry, the url and attributes of the avatar, the content of the post...

The script works for hundreds of other files/sites of this forum.

This is no encode/decode problem. And it is not "limited" to the XUSER part. I tried to "hardcode" the username, then the date of registry will fail. If I skip those, the text of the post (code see below) will fail...

```
#text of getpost
text = etree.tostring(p.find(XTEXT),pretty_print=True)
```

Now, this whole error would make sense if my xpath would be wrong. However, all the other files and the first numbers of users in this file work. it is only this "one" at position()=11

Is position() uncapable of going >10 ? I don't think so?
Am I missing something?

Comment: This might not solve your problem and I'm just wild-guessing, but I noticed that you're referring to position 11, when you only have 10 records on that page.

Comment: In addition, I was having some problems with xpath as well, so I decided to try PyQuery, which is Python's equivalent for jQuery, and it works quite well. You can use selectors, which will make your life way easier for extracting information.

Comment: I recommend using `lxml.html` instead of `lxml.etree` for parsing the html file in question. as for the errors, try printing the post in question that's causing the error using `html.tostring`, and see if it really has the structure you expect it should have, eventually post the result here. Also, I see you're using absolute xpaths, you could even try to prefix the xpaths that extract information with a '//', in case there is a wrapper element around the problematic post, it could find the information within it too.

Comment: @miguelcaires yes there are 10 "posts" on that page, however the tr[position()=2] is post #1, position()=11 is the post #10 by tompson that is making trouble

Comment: As @andrean suggested, parsing with `lxml.html` works for me: `import lxml.html` then `lxml.html.parse("http://www.razyboard.com/system/morethread-alte-korken-fruchtweinkeller-89069-6046822-0.html")`. I am able to print all usernames with the rest of your code and XPath expressions.

Comment: @paul.t
I have absolutely no experience with lxml.html and will look into it.

If it can save me some headache, it might actually be worth it...

Answer (score 1):

Question answered!

I have found the answer...

I must have been very tired when I tried to fix it and came here to ask for help. I did not see something quite obvious...

The way I posted my problem, it was not visible either.

- the HTML I downloaded and processed with tagsoup had an additional  tag at position 11... this was not visible on the website and screwed with my xpath
  (It probably is crappy html generated by the forum in combination with tagsoups attempt to make it parseable)
  out of >20000 files less than 20 are afflicted, this one here just happened to be the first...
- additionally sometimes the information is in table[4], other times in table[5]. I did account for this and wrote a function that will determine the correct table. Although I tested the function a LOT and thought it working correctly (hence did not inlcude it above), it did not.
  So I made a better xpath:

  '/html/body/table[tr/td[@width="20%"]]/tr[position()>1]'

and, although this is not related, I ran into another problem with unxpected encoding in the html file (not utf-8) which was fixed by adding:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='ISO-8859-15')  
t = etree.parse(forumfile, parser)
```

I am now confident that after adjusting for strange additional and multiple ,  and  tags my code will work on all files...

Still I will be looking into lxml.html, as I mentioned in the comment, I have never used it before, but if it is more robust and may allow for using the files without tagsoup, it might be a better fit and save me extensive try/except statements and loops to fix the few files screwing with my current script...